# Steps to update vendor files after pulling changed composer.lock file

Tags: updating, composer

Let's say I work in a group and somebody else did `composer update` and pushed changed `composer.lock` file. I pulled it and now I have to do update too, to match the files from changed lock file.

In symfony I would delete vendor dir and run `composer install`. But in drupal not all files are in vendor dir.

What is the best workflow in this case? Should I manually delete old vendor files (what dirs exactly?) or there is some composer command that will do all the work for me - check current vendor files with versions from composer.lock file and update what has to be updated?

Comment: can't you just do a `composer update` too and because of the lock file you'll get the same versions as the other person. composer should hopefully handle any package upgrades/downgrades to match the lock file

Comment: Put _everything_ into composer, will save you a lot of troubles. To get patches into `composer.json`, use [cweagans/composer-patches](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches). For JS libs use [Asset Packagist](https://asset-packagist.org/). This covered almost all my use-cases in the last two years. If that still doesn't cover all cases, add e.g. your private gibhub repo as a `repository` of type `vcs` into your `composer.json`

Comment: @Leigh that exactly my question is. If I go for "composer update" will it install version stored in lock file or install the newest possible, allowed by composer.json file?

Comment: @Hudri if everything is into composer and I have updated composer.lock file what command should I executed to update my local vendor files to the same versions as in composer.lock file. I think that calling "composer update" will not look composer.lock but updates to the newest allowed in composer.json

Comment: I usually run `composer install`, AFAIK only `install` guarantees the exact same set of code on every instance. `update` does not guarantee the same set of code (mostly it will result in the same, but it might also deliver newer versions if allowed in `composer.json`)

Comment: @Hudri so if someone else on project does "composer update" and then gives me modified composer.lock file I have to run "composer install" and we will both have the same versions of vendor files? Right?

Comment: Yes, that's the point of the lock file

Answer (score 1):

> In symfony I would delete vendor dir and run composer install. But in
>   drupal not all files are in vendor dir.
>
> What is the best workflow in this case? Should I manually delete old
>   vendor files (what dirs exactly?)

See .gitignore in your project dir:

```
# Ignore directories generated by Composer
/drush/contrib/
/vendor/
/web/core/
/web/modules/contrib/
/web/themes/contrib/
/web/profiles/contrib/
/web/libraries/
```

In case you want to do a fresh start with `composer install` you can delete all files with:

```
git clean -fdx .
```

See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clean/1.7.0

Comment: Ok, but main question here is do I have to delete those files manually or running "composer install" will make sure that all my vendor files are up to date with composer.lock file? I don't want fresh start - I want the simplest way to update vendor files after composer.lock file has been changed (by someone else on the project).

Comment: My answer is about the hypothetical question "In symfony I would delete vendor ...", if you need to do something similar in Drupal. But normally you don't need a fresh start every time composer.lock has changed.